# Exercise with polynomials

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials P(x) such that

1. the degree of P(x) is 3
2. P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=0

My try:

So since P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=0 then 1, 2 and 3 are roots of P(x) therefore there exist a Q(x), R(x) and L(x) such that:

$$P(x)=\begin{cases}(x-1)Q(x)\\(x-2)R(x)\\(x-3)L(x)\end{cases}$$

By equivalence and since the degree of P(x) is 3, there exist only one polynomial P(x) to satisfy the conditions we mentioned, which is: P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3) but we can multiply this polynomial with any real number and we will always get the same roots, so there exist infinite polynomials P(x)!

Is my solution correct?

Comment: The answer is no because a general polynomial of degree 3 (in your case) is A(x- 1)(x - 2)(x - 3) for some real number A.

Comment: Thus, there are more than one polynomial that satisfy the given requirement.

Comment: Yes, your solution seems correct to me, although I think the $P(X)=(x-1)Q(X)$ part etc can be omitted/ simplified. You can just say that $x-1|P(x)$, $x-2|P(x)$ and $x-3|P(x)$ and thus $P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)Q(x)$. You can deduce this by setting $P(x)=(x-1)S(x)$ and noting that $0=P(2)=1\cdot S(1)$.

Comment: Please give more precise context in the question. Is  this  problem from (pre)calculus (so the coefficients are real or complex numbers), or is it a problem from abstract algebra, where the coefficients may be from any ring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is sufficient to do this

$ P(x) = C(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

$ P(x) = Cx^3 - 6Cx^2 + 11Cx - 6C $

For any real number $ C \ne 0 $

Comment: Why would that be sufficient? The only way I can see to deduce sufficience is to do what the OP did in his question.

Comment: @DonAntonio , we can find one 3rd degree polynomial with the given roots , then multiply by any non zero constant.